# How to find sound pressure level of a line array in python?

Tags: python, audio, matplotlib, contour

I am wondering how to find the sound pressure level of a line array in python? Basically I want to draw a contour that shows the SPL based on the distance from the line array source of speakers. A sample contour is here:

[image]

The closest I got was from this snippet:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import linspace, meshgrid, sqrt, log

x = linspace(-30.0, 30.0, 15)
y = linspace(0, 30, 15)
X, Y = meshgrid(x, y)
Z = sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)

plt.figure()
CS = plt.contourf(Y, X, Z)
plt.show()
```

I know the contour I want is generated by sophisticated software and equations, but something close is fine for me.

This link might be helpful but I don't know how to get that contour with the equations from this info.
http://personal.cityu.edu.hk/~bsapplec/transmis1.htm

Thanks in advance,
dksr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I've done is create two little functions (lambda functions) in this snippet to calculate the pythagorean distance and the SPL according to equation [8] in your ref.

Furthermore, because the directivity factor is something determined experimentally, I have simply used cosine here as a representative example. You could replace the Q function with a function that given a angle theta and distance r returns a intensity score given some interpolation of experimental results.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import linspace, meshgrid, sqrt, log10, angle, cos

x = linspace(-30.0, 30.0, 15)
y = linspace(0, 30, 15)
X, Y = meshgrid(x, y)
#Z = sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)

def SPL(source_SPL, x, y, x1, y1, Q):
    '''Given a source sound pressure level, the x and y vectors describing
    the space, the x1 and y1 coordinates of the sound origin
    and a directivity factor function, return the SPL matrix'''
    #Using eqation 8 from the source
    dist = lambda x1, x2, y1, y2: sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)
    spl = lambda r, q: source_SPL - 20*log10(r) - 10*log10(q) - 11
    spl_matrix = []
    for y2 in y:
        # Create a new row
        spl_matrix.append([])
        for x2 in x:
            r = dist(x1, x2, y1, y2)
            theta = angle(complex(x2-x1, y2-y1))
            q = Q(theta, r)/float(source_SPL)
            # After calculating r and q, put them into the spl equation to get Db
            Db = spl(r, q)
            spl_matrix[-1].append(Db)
    return spl_matrix

Q = lambda theta, r: r*abs(cos(theta))
Z = SPL(1, x, y, 0.1, 0.1, Q)

plt.figure()
#Need to draw the contour twice, once for the lines (in 10 sections)
CS = plt.contour(Y, X, Z, 10, linewidths=0.5, colors='k')
#And again for the fills
CS = plt.contourf(Y, X, Z, 10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Although I've solved this without using arrays, you should look into numpy and how to vectorise this code so that you aren't using loops but matrix operations. That isn't so much of a code problem as a math problem however.

Finally, if you have a background in engineering, you can run this experiment on the computer where the Q function calculates the relative intensity based on environmental conditions. You'll need to understand more how the sound interacts with the surroundings, you might want to google finite element analysis and sound pressure level